# Erro: Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment

Tags: javascript

Estou "debugando" meus códigos jQuery e me deparei com este error na seguinte linha

```
while(match = regex.exec(item)) {
  [...]
```

error `Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.`

Comment: Esse é um erro do jslint, não?

Comment: Meu código é em uma unica linha, dai joguei no jsbin e deu isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não dá para avaliar se o seu código está correto ou não só por esse trecho, mas o que você está vendo é um erro apresentado por uma ferramenta de *linting*, provavelmente o [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) ou o [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). Não é um erro de sintaxe. Seu código pode estar funcionando corretamente ou não, mas essas ferramentas não têm como saber. Por isso elas te apontam o local de um possível problema, e aconselham que você não use esse tipo de sintaxe.

O problema em si é o operador de atribuição (`=`) dentro de uma expressão que espera um valor booleano (no caso o `while`, mas poderia ser um `if` ou um `for`). É possível que você queira de fato atribuir um valor a `match`, mas também é possível que na verdade você quisesse comparar o valor de `match` com o que está do outro lado do operador. Um exemplo mais claro, com `if`, é quando alguém escreve:

```
if(x = 5)
```

quando na verdade quer dizer

```
if(x == 5)
```

ou

```
if(x === 5)
```

O primeiro caso seria um erro de lógica (o código sempre irá entrar no `if`), e o linter quer evitar que você cometa esse tipo de erro proibindo que se use atribuição dentro de `if` ou dos inicializadores de `for` e `while`.

Mais detalhes no [JSLint Errors](https://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-assignment-expression).

---

**Nota:** você comentou que usou o JSbin no teste; o painel de erros dele usa um linter, por isso você viu esse erro lá.